# Yii url manager for modules is not working giving 404

Tags: php, yii

I have created  the module named enquiry in my project .

If I am running below line 
http://enqphp.intermesh.net/index.php?r=enquiry/Enquiryser/index/
then this URL is working perfectly. But I want it to be short like 
http://enqphp.intermesh.net/enquiry

For this, I have done some modifications in my `main.php` file in `URL manager` section:

```
return array(
   'caseSensitive' => true,
       'urlSuffix' => '/',
       'showScriptName' => false,
      'urlFormat' => 'path',
   'rules' =>
    array(
    '/' => array('site/index'),

    /* my files starting from here */
    '<modules>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<modules>/<controller>/view', '<modules>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<modules>/<controller>/<action>',
    '<modules>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/*' => '<modules>/<controller>/<action>',
    '/enquiry/'=>'enquiry/Enquiryser/index',
    ),
)
```

But it's not working and throwing 404 page not found .
Can anyone help me that what I am missing ?

Comment: check weather htaccess exists on server also check rewrite mod is enable or not?

Comment: For `enquiry` module, what is the class name generated. Means, when you created `enquiry` module -> Models, Controller & Views folder created along with one Enquiry.php . Correct ?

Comment: yes , Controller name is Enquiryser and action i am calling is index .

Answer (score 0):

What web server do you use? Nginx, Apache?

**Apache** 
To hide index.php in your URLs you can add mod_rewrite instructions to the .htaccess file in your document root or to the virtual host configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on

# prevent httpd from serving dotfiles (.htaccess, .svn, .git, etc.)
RedirectMatch 403 /\..*$
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

**Nginx**
You must have follwoing config for you server

```
location / {
        index  index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manual config of `yii\web\Application` by adding above lines to:`/path/to/your_app/common/config/main.php`:

```
'controllerMap' => [
    'abcd' => 'backend\controllers\BankController'
],
```

So the config file look likes: 
[image]